# How to update the records along with ICollection EF

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Without `ICollection`, I am able to update the data, but my attempts to update the `ICollection` records fail.

I tried the code shown here, but I get an error

> one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

I need to update the child records, and if records are not there, I need to insert them. Or we can delete and then insert. Please help - what did I do wrong?

`FHASMstBank` is the entity:

```
public partial class FHASMstBank
{
    public FHASMstBank()
    {
        this.FHASMstBankDomains = new HashSet<FHASMstBankDomain>();
        this.FHASMstBankProducts = new HashSet<FHASMstBankProducts>();
    }

    [Key]
    public short BankId { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string BankCode { get; set; }
    public string BankDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FHASMstBankDomain> FHASMstBankDomains { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FHASMstBankProducts> FHASMstBankProducts { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `UpdateBank` method. I'm passing the parameter as bank with updated values:

```
 public CreateBankResponse UpdateBank(Bank bank)
 {
     try
     {
         var mapper = _mapper.Map<FHASMstBank>(bank);
         var entity = _context.Set<FHASMstBank>().Local.FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.intBankID.Equals(bank.intBankID));

         entity.txtBankName = bank.txtBankName;
         entity.txtBankCode = bank.txtBankCode;
         entity.txtBankDescription = bank.txtBankDescription;
         entity.flgIsActive = bank.flgIsActive;
         entity.dtValidFrom = bank.dtValidFrom;
         entity.txtCreatedBy = bank.txtCreatedBy;
         entity.dtCreatedOn = bank.dtCreatedOn;
         entity.txtModifiedBy = bank.txtModifiedBy;
         entity.dtModifiedOn = bank.dtModifiedOn;
         entity.txtBankGroup = bank.txtBankGroup;
         entity.FHASMstBankDomains = bank.FHASMstBankDomains; //Icollection records
         entity.FHASMstBankProducts  = bank.FHASMstBankProducts;//Icollection records

         if (entity != null) // I'm using an extension method
         {
             // detach
             _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
         }

         // set Modified flag in your entry
         _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

         // save 
         var result = _context.SaveChanges(); // Getting error while saving

         if (result > 0)
         {
             return new CreateBankResponse(entity.intBankID, entity.txtBankName, entity.txtBankCode, true, null);
         }
         else
         {
             return new CreateBankResponse(entity.intBankID, entity.txtBankName, entity.txtBankCode, false, new string[] { "Bank Registration failed." });
         }
     }
     catch (DbUpdateException e)
     {
         return new CreateBankResponse(0, string.Empty, string.Empty, false, new string[] { e.Message, e.InnerException.Message });
     }
     catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
     {
         return new CreateBankResponse(0, string.Empty, string.Empty, false, new string[] { e.Message, e.InnerException.Message });
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by below code.

```
     public CreateBankResponse UpdateBank(Bank bank)
 {

     try
     {
         var mapper = _mapper.Map<FHASMstBank>(bank);
         var entityParent = _context.Set<FHASMstBank>().Local.FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.intBankID.Equals(bank.intBankID));
         entityParent.txtBankName = bank.txtBankName;
         entityParent.txtBankCode = bank.txtBankCode;
         entityParent.txtBankDescription = bank.txtBankDescription;
         entityParent.flgIsActive = bank.flgIsActive;
         entityParent.dtValidFrom = bank.dtValidFrom;
         entityParent.txtCreatedBy = bank.txtCreatedBy;
         entityParent.dtCreatedOn = bank.dtCreatedOn;
         entityParent.txtModifiedBy = bank.txtModifiedBy;
         entityParent.dtModifiedOn = bank.dtModifiedOn;
         entityParent.txtBankGroup = bank.txtBankGroup;

         if (entityParent != null)
         {
             // Update parent
             _context.Entry(entityParent).CurrentValues.SetValues(bank);
             // Delete Geo children
             foreach (var existingChild in entityParent.FHASMstBankGeoMappings.ToList())
             {
                 if (!bank.FHASMstBankGeoMappings.Any(c => c.intID == existingChild.intID))
                     _context.FHASMstBankGeoMappings.Remove(existingChild);
             }
             // Insert Geo children
             foreach (var childModel in bank.FHASMstBankGeoMappings)
             {
                 _context.FHASMstBankGeoMappings.Add(childModel);
             }

             // Delete Domain children
             foreach (var existingChild in entityParent.FHASMstBankDomains.ToList())
             {
                 if (!bank.FHASMstBankDomains.Any(c => c.intDomainID == existingChild.intDomainID))
                     _context.FHASMstBankDomains.Remove(existingChild);
             }
             // Insert Domain children
             foreach (var childModel in bank.FHASMstBankDomains)
             {
                 _context.FHASMstBankDomains.Add(childModel);
             }

             // Delete Products children
             foreach (var existingChild in entityParent.FHASMstBankProducts.ToList())
             {
                 if (!bank.FHASMstBankProducts.Any(c => c.intBankProductsID == existingChild.intBankProductsID))
                     _context.FHASMstBankProducts.Remove(existingChild);
             }
             // Insert Products children
             foreach (var childModel in bank.FHASMstBankProducts)
             {
                 _context.FHASMstBankProducts.Add(childModel);
             }

             // Delete Components children
             foreach (var existingChild in entityParent.FHASMstBankComponents.ToList())
             {
                 if (!bank.FHASMstBankComponents.Any(c => c.intBankComponentID == existingChild.intBankComponentID))
                     _context.FHASMstBankComponents.Remove(existingChild);
             }
             // Insert Components children
             foreach (var childModel in bank.FHASMstBankComponents)
             {
                 _context.FHASMstBankComponents.Add(childModel);
             }

         }

         // save 
         var result = _context.SaveChanges();

         if (result > 0)
         {
             return new CreateBankResponse(entityParent.intBankID, entityParent.txtBankName, entityParent.txtBankCode, true, null);

         }
         else
         {
             return new CreateBankResponse(entityParent.intBankID, entityParent.txtBankName, entityParent.txtBankCode, false, new string[] { "Bank Registration failed." });

         }
     }
     catch (DbUpdateException e)
     {
         return new CreateBankResponse(0, string.Empty, string.Empty, false, new string[] { e.Message, e.InnerException.Message });

     }
     catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
     {
         return new CreateBankResponse(0, string.Empty, string.Empty, false, new string[] { e.Message, e.InnerException.Message });
     }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection)

Enable library by:

```cs
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
    // Configuration code
});
```

Add `EqualityComparison` to mapping collection items. I don't know which classes you are using, so I will use my own classes as an example.

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<MstBankDomain, FHASMstBankDomain>().EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.Id == o.Id);
cfg.CreateMap<MstBankProducts, FHASMstBankProducts>().EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.Id == o.Id);
```

Then simplify your code to just `Map`. You do not need any state manipulations:

```cs
public CreateBankResponse UpdateBank(Bank bank)
{
    try
    {
        // load entity from database, with collections
        var entity = _context.Set<FHASMstBank>()
            .Include(b => b.FHASMstBankDomains)
            .Include(b => b.FHASMstBankProducts)
            .FirstOrDefault(b => b.intBankID == bank.intBankID);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            // map DTO to new entity
            entity = _mapper.Map<FHASMstBank>(bank);
            _context.Set<FHASMstBank>().Add(entity);
        }
        else 
        {
            // map DTO to existing entity with collections
            _mapper.Map(bank, entity);
        }

        // save 
        var result = _context.SaveChanges(); // Getting error while saving

        if (result > 0)
        {
            return new CreateBankResponse(entity.intBankID, entity.txtBankName, entity.txtBankCode, true, null);
        }
        else
        {
            return new CreateBankResponse(entity.intBankID, entity.txtBankName, entity.txtBankCode, false, new string[] { "Bank Registration failed." });
        }
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException e)
    {
        return new CreateBankResponse(0, string.Empty, string.Empty, false, new string[] { e.Message, e.InnerException.Message });
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        return new CreateBankResponse(0, string.Empty, string.Empty, false, new string[] { e.Message, e.InnerException.Message });
    }
}
```